# Please help! Trying to write a Program that uses today's date

Tags: c, time.h

For class, my professor gave us an extra credit assignment that we can do if we want.  I am having trouble with one part of it since she wants us to do something we did not learn in class yet.  The question is to create a program where they enter their birthday and then there is a function that will show how many days old they are.  I have done some research and found that I have to use something with time.h, and also I need to convert their birthday into Epoch time and subtract that from today's Epoch time.  I am not exactly sure how everything in my code works:  (Also I do not have to worry about leap days)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>


int main() {
    int month, day, year, AgeinDays;

    printf("Enter birthday (mm): ");
    scanf("%d", &month);
    printf("Enter birthday (dd): ");
    scanf("%d", &day);
    printf("Enter birthday (yyyy): ");
    scanf("%d", &year);

    AgeinDays = calc_age(month, day, year);
    printf("%d", AgeinDays);
}

int calc_age(int m, int d, int y) {
    int DaysinMonth[12] = {31, 28, 31, 20, 31, 31, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

    struct tm t;
    time_t t_of_day;

    t.tm_year = //Need to subtract todays year form y
    t.tm_mon = m;          
    t.tm_mday = d;          
    t.tm_isdst = -1;        
    t_of_day = mktime(&t);

    printf("You are this many seconds old", (long) t_of_day);
}
```

Comment: On Linux, see  "man 7 time" for an overview", and "man mktime" ... that should get you going on using the time functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how familiar you are with the concept of [unix time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). It's a system to discribe a point in time by counting the seconds from the first January of 1970. To get the number of days from a particular date to now, you can subtract the timestamps and devide the result by 86400 (=60*60*24). Thereby you don't have to think about leap years. If you are 8000 days old, you are 8000 days old. It doesn't matter if a year has 5 or 365.25 days.
To continue with your solution (time.h) you could try something like this:

```
double calc_age(const unsigned int m, const unsigned int d, const unsigned int y) {
    

    struct tm t = {0};
    time_t t_of_day;

    t.tm_year = y - 1900; // look at the documentation of struct tm
    t.tm_mon = m - 1;          
    t.tm_mday = d;          
    t.tm_isdst = -1;        
    t_of_day = mktime(&t);
    
    time_t now;
    time(&now);

    return  round((difftime(now,t_of_day)/(60.0*60.0*24.0)));
```

}

Please keep in mind that your solution with mktime might not work with dates before 1970. And you have to make some adjustments in the rest of your code (printf, foward decleration etc. ) Last note: My code is not a perfect solution maybe you think again about the data types and the rounding.

Comment: `struct tm t;` may have other  member than the usual 9.  Best to zero `t` with `struct tm t = {0};` first.

Comment: `difftime()` is also useful to find the _portable_  time difference.

Comment: Yes, you are totally right. I just wrote something down to show the idea. I edited the suggestions, i hope that's okay.

Comment: "devide the result by 86400 (=60*60*24)." --> consider _divide_ by `60.0*60*24` should code ever port ot a 16-bit embedded processor.  `60*60*24` overflows 16-bit `int`.

Comment: I changed the data types as well, because forced casting is in general not a good idea.